# How can I fix the problem of floating nodes in Pspice?

Tags: circuit-analysis, pspice, orcad

I have so many errors saying there is floating nodes in my circuit, I used a grounded big resistance in some nodes to fix them but there are so many floating nodes errors yet, my circuit is very large and I wish you could see the nodes...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Nc0.png)

[image]

Comment: Yes they are floating. Why did you do that ?

Comment: Often, those are warnings, only, which means the simulation should run. Otherwise, you could add the option `gshunt=1e-12...1e-9`, or any other value that adds a conductance from every node to ground (what `gshunt` does) without interfering with your elements -- I see you have some nF capcs in there, if my guess is right. Or try to break down the circuit and take it one step at a time, this is a rather common problem in large circuits.

Comment: Dear @aconcernedcitizen thanks for your answer